# HTML element set to visible but still invisible

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a website and I have an element that I have explicitly declared: `display: inline-block` and `visibility: visible` however, the element is still invisible. This is only occurring on mobile devices. The invisible element is `<div id="clock">`.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bitwise';
  src: url('bitwise.ttf');
  font-display: swap;
}

* {
  font-family: 'bitwise', monospace;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

:root {
  background-color: #008080;
}

body,
html,
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

span {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18pt;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  font-family: 'bitwise', monospace;
  background-color: #535353;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18pt;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

img:not(.noresize) {
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
}

video {
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
}

a:link {
  color: #EFCF7C;
}

a:visited {
  color: #105733;
}

button {
  background-color: #105733;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}

#back {
  background-color: #660000;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}

#taskbar {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 27px;
  background-color: silver;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px #dfdfdf, inset 0px 2px #ffffff;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#start {
  float: left;
}

#clock {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#clocktime {
  font-family: 'Arial', serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 23px;
  left: 17px;
}

#icons {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

#content {
  width: 675px;
  height: 300px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px) {
  html,
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #clock {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #clocktime {
    font-family: 'Arial', serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 23px;
    left: 17px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="taskbar">
  <div id="start"><img class="noresize" src="/assets/start.png"></div>
  <div id="clock"><img class="noresize" src="/assets/clock.png">
    <div id="clocktime"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="icons"><img class="noresize" src="/assets/icons.png"></div>
<div class="center"><img class="noresize" src="/assets/ie.png"></div>
<div class="center" id="content">
  Content here.
</div>
```

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1730a.png) - What the page should look like. Note the clock in the lower-right corner.

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7SCt.png) - What the page actually looks like on mobile.

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd2VW.png) -  Chrome DevTools showing the element as being in a visible spot, but still not being visible.

Comment: Maybe your element is off-screen or hidden beneath another element? Use browser mobile preview and check it then

Comment: @Justinas I can confirm the element is not below anything and not off-screen per DevTools, unless the DevTools preview is misleading for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I see that that css is only appliable when max-width is equal to 1079px.

Try to increase that number in inspector element to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had `overflow: hidden` set on `#taskbar` and this means that any children inside of the taskbar will not display, even if they are in a "visible" area. Adding `bottom: 32px` to set it inside of the taskbar worked.

Updated CSS:

```css
#taskbar {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 27px;
    background-color: silver;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px #dfdfdf, inset 0px 2px #ffffff;
}

<snip>

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px) {
    #clock {
        bottom: 32px;
    }
}
```